# pivot data from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

input table

```
country tag short
UK  F1  Units
UK  F2  Volume
UK  F3  Value
FR  T3  Units
FR  T2  Volume
FR  T1  Value
```

result output i want :

```
country Units Volume Value
uk      f1      f2      f3
fr      t1      t2      t3
```

Comment: SQL SERVER DBMS

Answer (score 1):

If there are a fixed number of different short values, simply use `case` expressions to do *conditional aggregation*:

```
select country,
       max(case when short = 'Units' then tag end) as Units,
       max(case when short = 'Volume' then tag end) as Volume,
       max(case when short = 'Value' then tag end) as val
from tablename
group by country
```

Comment: NO , short and tags are not fixed , there are thousands of rows . I can't use case here

Answer (score 1):

For solution you have to use dynamic pivoting.

```
create table #temp
(
     country varchar(30),tag varchar(20),short varchar(300)
) 
insert into #temp values ('UK',  'F1',  'Units')
insert into #temp values ('UK',  'F2' , 'Volume')
insert into #temp values ('UK'  ,'F3', 'Value')
insert into #temp values ('FR',  'T3' , 'Units')
insert into #temp values ('FR' , 'T2',  'Volume')
insert into #temp values ('FR',  'T1' , 'Value')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.short) 
            FROM #temp c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT country, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select country
                    , tag
                    , short
                from #temp
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(tag)
                for short in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '


execute(@query)

drop table #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Table Structure

```
 CREATE TABLE tablename
  (
     [country] [NVARCHAR](10) NULL,
     [tag]     [NVARCHAR](10) NULL,
     [short]   [NVARCHAR](10) NULL
  )

INSERT INTO tablename
VALUES      
('UK','F1','Units'),
('UK','F2','Volume'),
('UK','F3','Value'),
('FR','T3','Units'),
('FR','T2','Volume'),
('FR','T1','Value');
```

Using Pivot function

```
SELECT *
FROM   tablename
       PIVOT ( Max(tag)
             FOR short IN ([Units], [volume], [Value]) ) piv;
```

<sup>Online Demo: [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69eee/7/0)</sup>

Using Dynamic SQL PIVOT

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(max),
        @query AS NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @cols = Stuff((SELECT distinct ',' + Quotename(short)
                      FROM   tablename
                      FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1,'');

SET @query = 'SELECT * 
              FROM   tablename        
                     PIVOT ( Max(tag)              
                           FOR short IN (' + @cols + ') ) piv;';

EXECUTE(@query);
```

<sup>Online Demo: [Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69eee/6/0)</sup>

Result

```
+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| country | Units | volume | Value |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+
| FR      | T3    | T2     | T1    |
| UK      | F1    | F2     | F3    |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

Comment: I'm glad it helped.

Comment: using pivot worked , dynamic sql pivot is not giving me desired result

Comment: Hey @sheetalverma, your desired result in the question is wrong. But I don't think you're referring to that. 
How does it change from what you want..? What do you expect and what does this query give you?
If you can give me more details, I might be able to help you.
Btw, you can also check this query using this [online demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/69eee/6/0).

Comment: hey , anyway pivot method worked with the output I want , so thank you ..dynamic pivot is also correct  but i need different output , that's all.

Comment: If you can explain it, I or someone else on this community might be able to help you. Since the pivot method works, it might not be difficult to change the dynamic query.